# SVG fill hover effect with CSS, JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have inline SVG map on my HTML5 page, which I am trying to animate.

Each region on my map has separate path.

The effect I am trying to achieve is filling region path animation when hovering certain region. (Example: fill (color) goes from left to right)

It is easy to add a hover effect with CSS. (Example: targeting path class and using fill -> target:hover {fill: red;}, but if I add css animation it does not work for some reason.

Once again my goal is to animate the **fill color** when hovering on region, not the **stroke**.

I saw many tuts on animating the stroke, but almost none - animating the path color itself.

I am accepting JS solutions aswell. I think there is some sort of a trick with adding a clippath property to the svg path?

I am attaching images with better explanation.

So, lets imagine this is one of my map region. It has own path.

https://prnt.sc/vzvjc4

This is the effect I am trying to achieve. (Orange fill goes from bottom to top for example with)

https://prnt.sc/vzvk04

Comment: you should add the images into your answer

Comment: Have the fill be a linear gradient and animate the stops on hover.